# MYSQL Converting the australian time

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have Date, Time field in database which contains local Date, time where data was entered.

I need to convert that time to NSW time.  But its not working as expected.

```
set @state='Adelaide';

    CASE WHEN (@state ='NNSW')  THEN concat(`date`,' ',`time`)  
    WHEN    (@state ='SNSW')  THEN concat(`date`,' ',`time`)  
    WHEN (@state    ='Sydney')THEN concat(`date`,' ',`time`)  
    ELSE CONVERT_TZ(concat(`date`,' ',`time`)  , 'UTC', 'Australia/NSW')    END 
        from tablea;
```

Example:

```
Date             Time            NSW Time
2015-01-29  00:15:00.000000 2015-01-29 11:15:00.000000
2015-01-31  00:15:00.000000 2015-01-31 11:15:00.000000
2015-01-29  00:15:00.000000 2015-01-29 11:15:00.000000
2015-01-27  00:15:00.000000 2015-01-27 11:15:00.000000
2015-01-28  00:15:00.000000 2015-01-28 11:15:00.000000
```

If you see that 11 hours added for NSW time, compared to Adelaide time.  But timing difference for those region is only 30 mins. Please let me know how to resolve the problem.

Comment: You're converting from UTC to AEST - that's a difference of 11 hours. you want to use `Australia/South` instead of `UTC`

Comment: As a side note, if you're just storing the local date and state, you'll end up with ambiguous data for one hour per year. That *may* not matter to you, but you should consider it carefully. If your date/time values are all in the past, you may well want to store UTC values instead, for simplicity.

Comment: Thanks Jan Skeet for your suggestion.